# Java selenium - null pointer exception on webDriver inheritance

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I am getting null pointer exception. Would you be able to help and what should be fixed ?

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at pages.LandingPage.acceptConsent(LandingPage.java:14)
>
> at
> stepDefs.LandingPageStepDefs.customerAcceptsCookieConsent(LandingPageStepDefs.java:22)
>
> at ✽.Customer accepts cookie
> consent(file:///C:/Users/Bartek/IdeaProjects/Cucumber/src/test/java/features/interia.feature:5)

```
Feature: test of a webpage

  @desktop
  Scenario: Test landing page
    Given Customer accepts cookie consent
    And I click "OK" button at the bottom of the page

====================================================


package stepDefs;

import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import pages.LandingPage;


import static utils.BasePage.driver;

@Slf4j
public class LandingPageStepDefs {

    LandingPage landingPage = new LandingPage(driver);

    @And("Customer accepts cookie consent")
    public void customerAcceptsCookieConsent() {
        landingPage.acceptConsent();
    }

    @And("I click {string} button at the bottom of the page")
    public void iClickButtonAtTheBottomOfThePage(String text) {
        landingPage.clickButtonAtTheBottom(text);
    }


}


====================================================

package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import utils.BasePage;

public class LandingPage extends BasePage {

    public LandingPage(WebDriver driver) {
        super(driver);
    }

    public void acceptConsent() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//p[contains(text(), 'Consent')]")).click();
    }

    public void clickButtonAtTheBottom(String text) {
        String xpath = String.format("//div[@id='cNag']//a[contains(text(), '%s')]", text);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
    }
}


===================================================
package utils;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;


public class BasePage {

    @Getter @Setter
    public static WebDriver driver;

    public BasePage() {
    }

    public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

}
===============================================

package utils;

import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;
import io.cucumber.java.BeforeAll;
import io.cucumber.java.Scenario;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.devtools.DevTools;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Hook extends BasePage {



    @BeforeAll
    public static void beforeAll() {
        // Runs before all scenarios
    }

    @Before("not @mobile")
    public void beforeDesktop(Scenario scenario) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//Bartek//eclipse-workspace/chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://www.netcarshow.com/");

    }

}
```

I am adding pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Cucumber</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.cucumber/cucumber-junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>7.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.assertj/assertj-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.23.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
            <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.26</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/51648/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

All the hooks, inheritance, and attribute initialization makes reasoning how the initialization code run very difficult. Probably it would require lots of debugging to understand how it works ATM.

I would suggest simply re-writing it to be cleaner.

E.g.

On the Hooks, you can configure one static class that will hold the driver.

```
@Before("not @mobile")
    public void beforeDesktop(Scenario scenario) {
        
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//Bartek//eclipse-workspace/chromedriver.exe");
        val driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        // driver.get("https://www.netcarshow.com/"); -> Removing it on purpose
        DriverWrapper.setDriver(driver);

    }
```

This class would be something like:

```
public static class DriverWrapper {
  @Setter @Getter
  private Driver driver;
}
```

Then on your steps, simply use it.

```
@Slf4j
public class LandingPageStepDefs {

   LandingPage landingPage;

   @Given("The user accesses the home page")
   public void customerAcceptsCookieConsent() {
      landingPage = new LandingPage(DriverWrapper.getDriver());
   }

   @And("Customer accepts cookie consent")
   public void customerAcceptsCookieConsent() {
       landingPage.acceptConsent();
   }

   @And("I click {string} button at the bottom of the page")
   public void iClickButtonAtTheBottomOfThePage(String text) {
       landingPage.clickButtonAtTheBottom(text);
   }


}
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you detail the error?
Are you sure beforeDesktop runs before customerAcceptsCookieConsent?

Comment: The problem was solved, it was not in the code but in intellij runner configuration.